# XE6 IOS app upload failure

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe6

I have built an app using XE6 trial and when I have tried to upload to the app store I get the error:
This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the app store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 or higher and iOS 7 SDK. Do not build with beta software.

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 on the machine and iOS 7 SDK.

Is the problem because the trial version of XE6 is seen as beta software?

Comment: Did you read the licence that you agreed to? What does it say? Surely you aren't allowed to do this.

Comment: I could find no indication of this, but if that is the case then I can stop looking for another issue.

Comment: I built the app in a registered version of XE5 and it worked OK. It seems the trial version is seen as beta. Not unreasonable.